# Преобразование формата исполняемого файла MCU из Intel Hex и map в ELF

Tags: gdb, elf

Есть компилятор си, который не генерирует `elf`-файл, а его хочет отладчик. Нужно подружить. Как вариант - сделать простенький конвертер `hex+map` (или ещё какие файлы)`->elf.`
Под `Windows`. Есть ли где почитать про создание `elf`-файлов и что там для `gdb` должно быть?

Платформа: stm8

Comment: А в каком формате файл? И почему Вы решили, что gdb под windows требует elf? Или под виндами должен быть только конвертор? MCU -- это микроконтроллер? Какой? И почему gdb, там, скорее всего есть другой отладчик?

Comment: Любой микроконтроллер STM8, есть gdb-сервер от STMicroelectronics. Их официальный ассемблер производит elf-файлы, которые прицепляются к gdb весьма успешно. Других отладчиков нема. Конвертер под винды, хотя какая разница, переписать нехитрое дело.

Comment: [Это не поможет ?](https://wiki.freebsd.org/LibElf)